# Why is Bitmap serializable using DataContractSerializer but BitmapImage is not?

Tags: wpf, bitmap, datacontractserializer, bitmapimage

I have a WPF project where I used a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` property bound to UI. This is deserialized and serialized using a `DataContractSerializer`. If I change this to `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` then I get null `StreamSource` after deserialization?

On looking up in SO I found out that it is not possible/advisable to serialize `BitmapImage`. Can anyone please tell me why it is not possible?

Thank you.

Comment: BitmapImage doesn't appear to be a standard library type. What's it's namespace?

Comment: thanks for replying. It is from `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace.

Comment: When you set the StreamSource property, you shouldn't serialize the bitmap, but the original stream buffer instead. If it's a MemoryStream, initialized from a byte array, you could easily serialize the byte array.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Clemens. I could understand from one of the similar questions that we should serialize data e.g. `byte[]` and not implementation e.g. `BitmapImage`. It makes sense to me as well. However, I am wondering **why** i shouldn't or I can not serialize it? I would like to understand what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

To direct answer your question: Bitmap can be serialized with DataContractSerializer because Bitmap implements ISerializable interface. What that means is developers of Bitmap class took special care to implement serialization\deserialization logic and made it available to you. Not so with BitmapImage class - it's even not marked with Serializable attribute, so it is not intended to be serialized directly. DataContractSerializer tries it's best, but it cannot serialize properties such as StreamSource without guidance, because Stream is abstract class and it has no idea how to serialize\deserialize that (suppose for example that StreamSource is FileStream - what should it do with that?).